How smooth is a flow with respect to initial conditions if a vector field is Hölder?
Suppose $V$ is a vector field in a neighborhood $U$ of a manifold $M$. This vector field is $C^\infty$ everywhere in $U$, except at isolated singularities where the regularity is only Hölder (say $C^{k+\epsilon}$, $k \in \mathbb N$). In particular, if we write $V$ in coordinates as $V^i \partial_{x_i}$, then the functions $V^i : U \to \mathbb R$ have continuous derivatives. The existence and uniqueness theorem for differential equations therefore gives a unique flow $\phi : U \times I \to M$, with $I$ an open interval around $0$ (possibly $I = \mathbb R$), which is differentiable in the $I$-coordinate.
My question. What can we say about the smoothness of $\phi$ with respect to the initial data?
Specifically I'm interested in knowing what the smoothness is of a fixed time map $\phi_t : U \to M$. Does anyone know of a result or argument that shows that the flows of Hölder vector fields are also Hölder?

I once needed a result like this, and couldn't find it anywhere in the literature, so I wrote up a proof in the appendix to this paper. The proof there just covers the $C^{1,\alpha}$ case, but as I remarked at the end of the paper, it can easily be adapted to show $C^{k,\alpha}$ regularity as well. (Also, as I noted there, the result is false for $k=0$.)
